# How many samples for accuracy assessment of remote sensing classification?

Tags: classification

I am extremely confused about the number of samples to gather in order to perform an accuracy assessment of remote sensing classification. Now, it is clear to me the concept of stratification, random etc.. but, there is still no clear guidelines on literature of how to chose the beast number of samples. Can somebody give some advices?

Thanks,
Paolo

Comment: Advice: turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. You see, your request boils down, more or less, to: "someone teach me the statistical knowledge for some specific use case". But this place is for specific questions on programming, it is not intended that some "tutor" sits down with you to understand what exactly you intend to do, where you are right now, what is missing, etc ....

Answer (score 0):

You may read following research paper for clear idea
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252668114_STUDY_OF_SAMPLING_METHODS_FOR_ACCURACY_ASSESSMENT_OF_CLASSIFIED_REMOTELY_SENSED_DATA

They suggest sample size of 100 as a relible size...